# Continuity of a Shannon entropy on $L_{1}([0,1]^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, lp-spaces, entropy

Let $I:L_1([0,1]^2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be a function defined by

$$I(W) = \int_{[0,1]^2} I_0(W(x,y)) dx dy $$

where $I_0(u) = -u\log(u)-(1-u)\log\left(1-u\right)$.

I sketched a proof of the continuity:

Let $W_m \rightarrow W$ be a pointwise convergent sequence.
Hence by dominated convergence theorem (DCT) $||W_n -W||_1 \rightarrow 0$. Since $I_0(\cdot)$ is continuous, then $I_0(W_n(x,y)) \rightarrow I_0(W(x,y))$. And by DCT, we obtain $I(W_n(x,y)) \rightarrow I(W(x,y))$.

Thus, $I(.)$ is pointwisely continuous. Hence $I(.)$ is continuous on  $L_{1}\left(\left[0,1\right]^2\right)$.

Is it correct this proof?

Comment: Are the function supposed to have values between $0$ and $1$? Otherwise, $I(W)$ may not be defined. Which dominating function do you choose?

Comment: Yes, the values are between 0 and 1.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I realized you are right. If we restrict W(x,y) to values in (0,1). I think the DCT can be applied?.